# Infinite loop in source with conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit

I decided to try and get a handle on conduit, and I thought I was doing well, but when I try to make this simple source with conduit 4, I get an infinite loop and I don't understand why.  This is simplified, the original version would create a temporary file name and return it via yield.  This just returns a ().

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.List as CL

tempfiles :: MonadIO m => Source m ()
tempfiles = loop
  where
    loop = do
      x <- liftIO $ print "tempfile"
      yield x
      loop
```

If I run:

```
runResourceT $ (tempfiles $$ CL.take 5)
```

I get an infinite loop.  Why doesn't it just run five times and give me a list of five ()s?

Comment: Minor nitpick: why `tempfiles = loop where loop = do ... loop` ? Why not just `tempfiles = do ... tempfiles`?

Comment: Because the mkstemp function in System.Posix.Temp requires an argument, so tempfiles itself needed one, but since I'm recursing and that argument doesn't change, rather than passing it in again, I just made a loop function to do recurse with which continually reuses the argument passed in at the top level.

Comment: Final result was this: https://gist.github.com/3051620 Which is damned cool, honestly.  An infinite lazy tempfile generator, essentially.  This library is fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In conduit 0.4, yield does not perform auto-termination. This is an important change in the 0.5 release; your code works as expected there.

Comment: Well I was waiting for http-conduit, but I guess that's a good enough reason to update now.  Thanks.